# Date in vba vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

The following code shows the Range("b2") is equal to #8/28/2018# and the first vlookup runs successfully, but the second vlookup returns an error.

Can anyone explain why it happens? Thanks.

```
Sub vlup()
Dim idx As Double
Dim dt As Date

If Range("b2") = #8/28/2018# Then
    MsgBox "They are equal. "
End If

dt = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("b2"), Range("b1:b11"), 1, False)
MsgBox "The 1st search is valid. "

dt = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(#8/28/2018#, Range("b1:b11"), 1, False)
MsgBox "The 2nd search is valid. "

End Sub
```

[The excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGv5D.png)

Comment: Comparison operator does some implicit things under hood. VLOOKUP doesn't.  This will work `WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(#8/28/2018#), Range("b1:b11"), 1, False)`. Read about Value2, aslo.

Comment: ^^this^^. You could also look for 43340.

Comment: @cyboashu@Jeeped Thanks for the comments. It seems the the stored value (maybe in the form of double) is compatible with the argument of vlookup function.